# export testcases/Reports from testlink to testRail

Tags: php, testlink, testrail

When I try to format the xml file exported from testlink to a testRail format using the command

```
php testlink2testrail.php BarreDeNavigationNouveau.xml BarreDeNavigationNouveauRail.xml
```

I got a newly generated file without test cases. This message is shown in the console

```
Successfully converted 10 sections and 0 cases

All configuration files "parsehtml.php  -- markdownify.php -- testlink2testrail.php" are OK.
```

I expected BarreDeNavigationNouveauRail.xml with all test cases, however this is not the case. How can I generate this XML file correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I attempted to reproduce the problem you reported, and I observed the same issue as you described. When I attempted to format the XML file from TestLink using the provided command:

****php testlink2testrail.php input-file output-file****

It resulted in the conversion of sections, but not the test cases themselves.

I think that this is the limitation of the outdated nature of the script provided in the TestRail documentation. The script seems not to be updated for a long time and hence it seems to be a bug or limitation here.

But there is an alternative solution. You can utilize a Python script which is now available for TestLink migration. You can find the link for it here:
https://github.com/gurock/testrail-custom/tree/master/testlink-migration

This Python script can convert XML files exported from TestLink into compatible CSV files, which can then be imported into TestRail.

In case you would like to export the test cases within the project in TestLink to TestRail, you can use the below script :

**python3 TestLink2TestRail.py -i inputfile -o outputfile**

Here **TestLink2TestRail.py** is the Python script that is responsible for converting the XML file to CSV file.

The **input file** is the XML file exported from the TestLink and

The **output file** is the newly generated CSV file that can be imported into TestRail

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).